# for loop after for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Basically this is a website scraper, but I am struggling to get the for loop done for the dates.

```
pickupdate = date(2022, 6, 16)
days_to_scrape = int(1)
days = timedelta(days=days_to_scrape)
returndate = pickupdate + days
Hire_Start = pickupdate.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
Hire_End = returndate.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

def offer(Hire_Start, Hire_End, req):
XXXXXXXXXXXXX
req_list = [cars, minibuses, trucks, vans] <-- these are the websites

for req in req_list:
    create_folder_structure(req, Hire_Start)
    offer(Hire_Start, Hire_End, req)
```

I would like to scrape every 1,7,14 and 28 days. So the variable days_to_scrape should do 1 first then 7 etc.

How can I achieve that?

Thx a lot (sorry if I got you confused)

Comment: is there any specific pattern you are following or it will be same [1,7,14,28] for every loop?

Comment: Same for every loop. I have 4 websites so will do this 1,7,14,28 for all 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list with 1, 7, 14, and 28. Iterate through it.

```
days_to_scrape = [1, 7, 14, 28]

for day_to_scrape in days_to_scrape:
    days_to_scrape2 = timedelta(days=day_to_scrape)
```

Comment: When I add this, it goes straight to 28 and skips 1, 7, 14

Comment: @Singh It seems unlikely

Comment: Can you pls show me how I can do this nested loop ? With for req in req_list:
    create_folder_structure(req, Hire_Start)
    offer(Hire_Start, Hire_End, req) and add days_to_scrape = [1, 7, 14, 28]

for day_to_scrape in days_to_scrape:
    days_to_scrape2 = timedelta(days=day_to_scrape)

Comment: @Singh If I'm right, it should not be nested inside your `req_list` loop. It should be the top-level loop inside which all your other code (from that post) should be present.